# How to remove gloss paint incorrectly applied to wainscoting over gloss paint

Tags: painting, paint-removal

A contractor installing and painting baseboards said he could paint the wainscoting in our half bath. It is gloss latex paint over the old gloss latex paint, but I don't think the walls were cleaned or prepared at all, and am sure they were not primed before the new coat, and over two weeks later I can use my fingernail to pierce the new paint and peel a 4 foot section down the wall. The wall here is covered in a plywood wainscoting with a small beaded double groove every 2 inches.

Since it is wainscoting, how can I remove this new coat, *including in the wainscoting grooves* so I can re-paint it properly? A paint scraper won't get in the grooves, at least not without damaging the bead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rip out and replace the wainscoting.  Wainscoting generally comes pre-primed.  For a little more at a better lumber yard, you can get a true plywood panel.  The big box stores will have MDF, which is much less durable.

You might be able to compel the contractor to do this.... but given the story above, you probably don't want them doing it.